# What is the big O of log(n^2) compared to log(n)?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I'm not quite sure if log(n^2) is on the same level of complexity of log(n) or not. It's been a while since I've taken precalculus and my knowledge of logs has deteriorated by a lot - if anybody could help explain this to me really quick, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`log(n^2) = 2 * log(n)` so it is comparable.

More generally speaking, `log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)` (the inverse function is exponential, and `exp(a+b) = exp(a) * exp(b)`

Comment: Ah wow, I can't believe I forgot that simple rule. Thanks a lot for the quick clear up.